# Asp.Net MVC 5 ModelState in a controller with index, add, edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, modelstate

I have a problem for use ModelState.
I use a controller for show a list, edit, and create a element.
I use partials views for create and edit. on the index view

My index view use a view model (contain a list of my model and the selected model)
My problem is I would like to show the validation error on my partial view.

Can you help me for add this modelState on my save function?

### RecordersViewModel.cs

```
public class RecordersViewModel
{
    public List<MapRecorders> Recorders { get; set; }
    public MapRecorders SelectedRecorder { get; set; }
    public string DisplayMode { get; set; }
}
```

### MapRecorders  (table db)

```cs
public partial class MapRecorders
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public MapRecorders()
    {
        this.Timers = new HashSet<Timers>();
    }
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int MapRecordersID { get; set; }
    
    [Display(Name = "Nom")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le nom est obligatoire.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### recordersController.cs

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (ScheduleRecDBEntities db = new ScheduleRecDBEntities())
    {
        List<MapRecordingtypes> recodersTypesModel = db.MapRecordingtypes.ToList();
        ViewData["RecordingTypeList"] = recodersTypesModel.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.MapRecordingtypesID.ToString(), Text = x.Name });

        RecordersViewModel model = new RecordersViewModel();
        model.Recorders = db.MapRecorders.OrderBy(m => m.MapRecordersID).ToList();
        model.SelectedRecorder = null;
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add()
{
    using (ScheduleRecDBEntities db = new ScheduleRecDBEntities())
    {
        List<MapRecordingtypes> recodersTypesModel = db.MapRecordingtypes.ToList();
        ViewData["RecordingTypeList"] = recodersTypesModel.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.MapRecordingtypesID.ToString(), Text = x.Name });

        RecordersViewModel model = new RecordersViewModel();
        model.Recorders = db.MapRecorders.OrderBy(
            m => m.MapRecordersID).ToList();
        model.SelectedRecorder = null;
        model.DisplayMode = "WriteOnly";
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    using (ScheduleRecDBEntities db = new ScheduleRecDBEntities())
    {
        List<MapRecordingtypes> recodersTypesModel = db.MapRecordingtypes.ToList();
        ViewData["RecordingTypeList"] = recodersTypesModel.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.MapRecordingtypesID.ToString(), Text = x.Name });

        RecordersViewModel model = new RecordersViewModel();
        model.Recorders = db.MapRecorders.OrderBy(
            m => m.MapRecordersID).ToList();
        model.SelectedRecorder = db.MapRecorders.Find(id);
        model.DisplayMode = "ReadWrite";
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(MapRecorders obj)
{
    using (ScheduleRecDBEntities db = new ScheduleRecDBEntities())
    {
        MapRecorders existing = db.MapRecorders.Find(obj.MapRecordersID);

        if (existing == null)
        {
            obj.Active =
                Convert.ToByte(Request.Form["Active"]
                    .ToString()); //Request.Form["Active"].ToString() == "false" ? 0 : 1;
            db.MapRecorders.Add(obj);
        }
        else
        {
            existing.Name = obj.Name;
            existing.Link = obj.Link;
            existing.LinkBackup = obj.LinkBackup;
            existing.MapRecordingTypesID = obj.MapRecordingTypesID;
            existing.Active =
                Convert.ToByte(Request.Form["Active"]
                    .ToString()); //Request.Form["Active"].ToString() == "false" ? 0 : 1;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        RecordersViewModel model = new RecordersViewModel();
        model.Recorders = db.MapRecorders.OrderBy(
            m => m.MapRecordersID).ToList();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Recorders");
    }
}
```

### index.cshtml

```
@model ScheduleRecordings.Models.RecordersViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 float-left btn-list titlebar">
        <h1>Liste des décodeurs</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit"
                   value="Ajouter" formaction="/Recorders/Add" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 float-left" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <form method="post">
            <table class="table-list" border="1" cellpadding="10">
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRecorder.MapRecordersID)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRecorder.Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRecorder.Link)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRecorder.LinkBackup)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRecorder.MapRecordingtypes.Name)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedRecorder.Active)</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Recorders)
                {
                    if (Model.SelectedRecorder != null)
                    {
                        if (item.MapRecordersID ==
                            Model.SelectedRecorder.MapRecordersID)
                        {
                            @:<tr class="SelectedRecorder">
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @:<tr>
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @:<tr>
                                }
                                <td>@item.MapRecordersID</td>
                                <td>@item.Name</td>
                                <td><a target="_blank" href="http://@item.Link">@item.Link</a></td>
                                <td><a target="_blank"  href="http://@item.LinkBackup">@item.LinkBackup</a></td>
                                <td>@item.MapRecordingtypes.Name</td>
                                <td>@Html.CheckBox("Active_" + @item.MapRecordersID.ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(@item.Active), new { @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit"
                                           formaction="/Recorders/Edit/@item.MapRecordersID"
                                           value="Editer" />
                                </td>
                                @:</tr>
                }
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 float-left">
        @{
            if (Model.SelectedRecorder != null)
            {
                if (Model.DisplayMode == "ReadOnly")
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial
                    ("ShowRecorder", Model.SelectedRecorder);
                }
                if (Model.DisplayMode == "ReadWrite")
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial
                    ("EditRecorder", Model.SelectedRecorder);
                }
            }
            if (Model.DisplayMode == "WriteOnly")
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("InsertRecorder",
                new ScheduleRecordings.Models.MapRecorders());
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

### InsertRecorder.cshtml

```
@using ScheduleRecordings.Models
@model ScheduleRecordings.Models.MapRecorders

@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "Recorders", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table-info" border="1" cellpadding="10">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <span>Ajouter</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @autofocus = "autofocus" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Link)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Link)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LinkBackup)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LinkBackup)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MapRecordingtypes.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MapRecordingTypesID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["RecordingTypeList"], "[Type]", new { @class = "form-control" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Active)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBox("Active", Convert.ToBoolean(Model.Active))</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Sauvegarder"
                       formaction="/Recorders/Save" />
                <input type="submit" value="Annuler"
                       formaction="/Recorders" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Link, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LinkBackup, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Hey, man can you pl elaborate on your question.

Comment: I would like to check if the model is validate on my save function.
And after, I would like return my index view with the partial view and the error message of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my solution.

I just forgot to call the validation.js script ...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of the question:

1:) Use ModeState.IsValid property in the save method. For This Simply use

```
 If(ModelState.IsValid)
{ 
   //Save Code
}
    else
{
   //Do Something
}
```

2:) You need to add Validation Messages to your ViewModel and also Add a validation message helper method to the Partial View. Like in the given reference to show the error message.

Link:-  https://forums.asp.net/post/6080694.aspx

**Edit**
add this type of validation to your ViewModel

```
[StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "The Description Can Not Exceed 2000 Characters")]
```

and add this type of validation helper method in the Partial View

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayMode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Can you show me for this point "add Validation Messages to your ViewModel " ?

Comment: Did That Answer Your Question?

Comment: I try now but the displayMode it's just use for know if I show the insert partial view or edit partial view... But how to display the errors of each field of the object ...

Comment: You can Check DATA ANNOTATIONS for that which allow you to validate different kinds of data and objects in your model. Also, You Can Create Your Own Model State Error in case you want to perform a special kind of validation.